# Get an item inside an array by its property

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I would like to assign the output from Array.filter to an existing array.

I'm working on nodejs socket service, and I have an array structured like this:

GROUPS = [{id: 1, members: ['user1', 'user2', ... ]}];

I would like to remove a user doing a map on GROUPS, with this:

```
GROUPS.map((group) => {
    group.members.map((member) => {
        const connectedClients = Array.from(wss.clients);
        const userIsConnected = connectedClients.some(existingMember => existingMember.id === member.id);
        if (!userIsConnected) {
            console.log('member: ', member.userID); // userid: 12345678
            console.log('group_id: ', group.id); // groupId: 123456677
            console.log('1. ', GROUPS[group.id]); // undefined

            GROUPS[group.id].members = group.members.filter(memberInGroup => memberInGroup !== member.id);
            console.log('group: ', GROUPS[group.id].members.length);
        }
    });
});
```

How can I do that association?

```
GROUPS[group.id].members = group.members.filter(memberInGroup => memberInGroup !== member.id);
```

Thank you!

Comment: why map and not using the retuned new array? do you have some data to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MDN docs on map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax)

```
arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

Your issue is, you're using the group.id as index, but basic knowledge about iterations is that first elements index is 0, whilst your IDs value is 1. Having an array with 10 elements, last elements index is 9, arr[9], trying to call arr[10] will result in error, like in your example.

You can use `forEach` cuz you don't seem to need the array output

```
GROUPS.forEach((group, index, arr) => {
  arr[index] = "..";
});
```